# Error in date formatting JS

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

in my ASP.net application, in the js, i got the date format as '2017-04-26T09:00:00Z'. What is this format? And when i return this to the view page, the date is changed to 26/04/2017 02:00 am. But the actual time is 09.00 am. Kindly help me why this is happening? My js code is

```
{
                "data": "Date",
                "render": function (data) {
                    return moment(data).format('MM/DD/YYYY H:m');
                }
            }
```

Comment: Are you sure that current `data` passed with local time instead of UTC? If it passed using local time, consider converting to UTC first before displaying.

Comment: Yeah, It is local time. And I'll try to convert it to UTC. Thank you

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601

Comment: You may need to use `toISOString()` before performing AJAX call, then display the result as local time.

Answer (score 4):

'Z' stands for Zulu time, which is also GMT and UTC.

moment is converting that timestamp (your variable data) to your local timezone which appears to be 7 hours behind GMT.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [W3scholls](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp) :

- Date and time is separated with a capital T
- UTC time is defined with a capital letter Z

And if you test [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_date_string_iso4) you will be get the secret behind this.

Answer (score -1):

The date you see in the JS is actually your the date Time with your timezone. On server side it will automatically get converted to the UTC timezone.

you must be at UTC + 7:00Hrs time zone right.

If you want to get the Date right just strip the Time part in JS,

```
moment(data).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
```

Comment: Depending on the time zone differences, the date alone can also be different

Comment: @Peter But I must want the time. It is important